# Is it sufficient for subspaces $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ or $W_2 \subseteq W_1$ to show intersection of affine subspaces is nonempty?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $W_1, W_2$ are subspaces of finite-dimensional vector space $V$ such that $W_2 \subseteq W_1$, then for any $v \in V$, isn't $v + W_2 \subseteq v + W_1$?

This question came up for me while proving the standard result that for 2 affine subspaces $\mathcal{A}_1,\mathcal{A}_2$ of $V$, $\mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2$ is an affine subspace or empty. So, say $\mathcal{A}_1 = u + W_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2 = v + W_2$ for $u,v \in V$. If $x \in \mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2$, then $x - u \in W_1$ and $x - v \in W_2 \subseteq W_1$. So we have $x \in v + W_2 \Longrightarrow x \in v + W_1$ which means $v + W_2 \subseteq v + W_1$; and also we have $x + W_1 = u + W_1 = v + W_1$. Thus, $\mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2 = \mathcal{A}_2$ which is an affine subspace.

So, isn't it sufficient that $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ or $W_2 \subseteq W_1$ so that $\mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2 \neq \emptyset$? Or must we have $W_1 = W_2$ and my logic is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> If $W_1, W_2$ are subspaces of finite-dimensional vector space $V$ such that $W_2 \subseteq W_1$, then for any $v \in V$, isn't $v + W_2 \subseteq v + W_1$?

Yes, indeed. Of infinite-dimensional spaces as well.

> If $x \in \mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2$, then $x - u \in W_1$ and $x - v \in W_2 \subseteq W_1$.

Where did "$\subseteq$" inclusion come from? This is wrong, you only get $x-v\in W_2$. Whatever follows after that is not good. Note that $\mathcal{A}_1\cap\mathcal{A}_2$ need not be neither $\mathcal{A}_1$ nor $\mathcal{A}_2$ (which is your conclusion). For example consider $\mathcal{A}_1=\{(0,y)\ |\ y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mathcal{A}_2=\{(x,0)\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ as affine subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then the intersection is the singleton $\{(0,0)\}$, although it still is an affine subspace.

So how to approach this? Well, you already know that $\mathcal{A}_1=u+W_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2=v+W_2$. Now what you don't realize is that if $x\in\mathcal{A}_1\cap\mathcal{A}_2$ (so the case when the intersection is nonempty) then $\mathcal{A}_1=x+W_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2=x+W_2$. And this leads to $\mathcal{A}_1\cap\mathcal{A}_2=x+W_1\cap W_2$.

Comment: The $\subseteq$ inclusion comes from the assumption that $W_2 \subseteq W_1$. If $x - v \in W_2$, then $x - v \in W_1$, right? Also doesn't $x + W_1 \cap W_2$ imply that $\mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2$ is always nonempty since we always have $0 \in W_1 \cap W_2$?

Comment: @CyCeez Again, where does the "$\subseteq$" assumption come from? You say yourself that you want to show that the intersection of two affine subspaces is an affine subspace. And suddenly, out of nowhere the "$W_2\subseteq W_1$" assumption appears. That doesn't make any sense. Also $\mathcal{A}_1\cap\mathcal{A}_2$ can be empty. I pick $x\in \mathcal{A}_1\cap\mathcal{A}_2$ and therefore I only consider the case when it is not empty. It can be empty as $\mathcal{A}_1=\{(0,t)\ |\ t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mathcal{A}_2=\{(1,t)\ |\ t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ example (i.e. two parallel lines) shows.

Comment: I created the assumption as part of the hypothesis. My question isn't really about how to prove the result but that if you add the condition $W_2 \subseteq W_1$ to the hypothesis, then is this true? But your original answer gave an example where that condition didn't need to happen and still you get an affine subspace.